# Why useEffect works only after manual reload?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I use react redux redux-toolkit
When switching to CardDetails, everything works and I get data in the state of only one element, but when I go from this page to any other page that has useEffect and in which I use the same state, it does not work and I have to reload the page manually. For what reason can this happen?
Here is the page code for one element

```
const CardDetails = () => {
const {id} = useParams()
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const location = useLocation()
const {posts, loading} = useSelector((state) => ({...state.posts}))
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPost(id))
}, []);
console.log(posts)
return (
    <div>
        <img style={{maxWidth: "150px"}} src={posts.img} alt="image"/>
    </div>
);
};
```

Here is the page I go to from CardDetails

```
const Main = () => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const {posts, loading} = useSelector((state) => ({...state.posts}))
const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('profile'))
useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getPosts())
}, []);

const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
const [description, setDescription] = useState("");
const [creator, setCreator] = useState("");
const [category, setCategory] = useState("");
const [img, setImg] = useState("");
const [tags, setTags] = useState(["tag1", "tag2"]);

const onSavePostClicked = () =>{
    const newPost = {title, description, category, img}
    dispatch(createPost(newPost))
    setTitle('')
    setDescription('')
    setCreator('')
    setCategory('')
    setImg('')
}

return (
```

And here is the postsSlice

```
import {createAsyncThunk, createSlice} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import * as api from "../../../api/index";
import {fetchPost, fetchPostsCategory} from "../../../api/index";
export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/getPosts',
async (thunkAPI)=> {
    const response = await api.fetchPosts()
return response.data.data
})
export const getPost = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/getPost',
async (id,thunkAPI)=> {
    const response = await api.fetchPost(id)
    return response.data.data
})
export const createPost = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/createPosts',
async (newPost,thunkAPI)=> {
    const response = await api.createPost(newPost)
    return response.data.data
})

export const deletePost = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/deletePost',
async (post,thunkAPI)=> {
    const {_id} = post
    const response = await api.deletePost(_id)
    return response.data
})

export const updatePost = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/updatePost',
async (post,thunkAPI)=> {
    const {_id} = post
    const postEdited = {...post, published: true}
    const response = await api.updatePost(_id, postEdited)
    return response.data
})
export const getCategory = createAsyncThunk(
'posts/getCategory',
async (category,thunkAPI)=> {
    const response = await api.fetchPostsCategory(category)
    return response.data.data
})

const initialState = {
posts: [],
loading: false,
error:null
}


export const postsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "posts",
  initialState,
  reducers:{
    postAdded: {
        reducer(state, action) {
            state.posts.push(action.payload)
        },
        prepare(title, description, creator, category, img) {
            return {
                payload: {
                    title,
                    description,
                    creator,
                    category,
                    img
                }
            }
        }
    },
    },
  extraReducers: {
    [createPost.pending]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
    },
    [createPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.posts.push(action.payload);
    },
    [createPost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload.message;
    },
    [getPosts.pending]: (state) => {
        state.loading = true
    },
    [getPosts.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.posts = action.payload
    },
    [getPosts.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.loading = false
    },
    [deletePost.fulfilled]: (state, action)=>{

        if (!action.payload?._id) {
            console.log('Delete could not complete')
            console.log(action.payload)
            return;
        }
        const { _id } = action.payload;
        state.posts = state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== _id);
    },
    [updatePost.pending]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = true;
    },
    [updatePost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        const { _id } = action.payload;
        state.loading = false;
        const posts = state.posts.filter(post => post._id !== _id);
        state.posts = [...posts, action.payload];
    },
    [updatePost.rejected]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false;
        state.error = action.payload.message;
    },
    [getCategory.pending]: (state) => {
        state.loading = true
    },
    [getCategory.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        console.log()
        state.posts = action.payload
    },
    [getCategory.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.loading = false
    },
    [getPost.pending]: (state) => {
        state.loading = true
    },
    [getPost.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
        state.loading = false
        state.posts = action.payload
    },
    [getPost.rejected]: (state) => {
        state.loading = false
    },
},
})


export const {postAdded} = postsSlice.actions


export default postsSlice.reducer
```

Comment: Can you show how do you use card detail?

Comment: @JulienKode ` <Route exact path="/publication/:id" element={<CardDetails/>}/>` in App.js

Comment: Are you using react router ?

Comment: have you try theses hooks on the docs ?
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/hooks/use-location

Comment: @JulienKode I already tried location hook before asking the question but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `useEffect` with an empty array as deps `[]` it will only be trigger when you mount your component (and cleaned when you unmount the component)

Comment: What should I use in [] to trigger it every time I go that component?

Comment: Which routing library are you using?

Comment: react-router-dom